# JavaScript refresh/reload page not supported by Safari and IE but works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, safari, refresh

I am struggling to fix this issue of reloading a page on successful click event. I tried different options, but they works fine with chrome, firefox and not with IE, safari.
E.g.

```
$(".delete_userbin").click(function () {
            .
            .
            .
            delete_confirmation();
    return false;
});

   function delete_confirmation(){
            $("#bin_confirmation").html("<span class='confirmation_text'>Are you sure?</span><a class='yes-delete-btn'></a><a class='no-delete-btn'></a>");     
        }

        $(".yes-delete-btn").live("click", function(){
            $.post( siteurl+"ajax/deletebin", { bundle_id: bundle_id, user_id: user_id });
            window.location.reload(true);               
        });
```

Safari reloads the page but does not shows me the difference. If i try to remove window.location.reload(true;, it will delete my bundle and will show me the difference only when I manually refresh the page (command+R). Can someone get the workaround by just one command that will be supported by all browser??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Comment: maybe wait for the jquery post method result. $.post( siteurl+"ajax/deletebin", { bundle_id: bundle_id, user_id: user_id },function(data){window.location.reload(true);});

Comment: Hi Murat, thank you very much. It worked and is supported by all browser. Between, can you please explain me the logic behind this? Why only chrome and Firefox was supporting previous code n not safari and IE?